# Android: Store the ratings in database

Tags: android, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

List view of ratings I am getting from web service I need to store the response of ratings in database. Ratings are storing but not according to the position if I given ratings to 1st person it is storing it to another please help me out.

```
public class FacultyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private final Context context;

        public FacultyListAdapter(Context context) {

            this.context = context;

            if (!facultylist.isEmpty()) {
                // courseEmptyLayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);
            }
        }



        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                            ViewGroup parent) {
            final ViewHolder TabviewHolder;

           // convertView = null;

            if (convertView == null) {

                TabviewHolder = new ViewHolder();


                //LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_feedback,
                        parent, false);

                TabviewHolder.FacultyName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.FacultyName);//facultyname

                TabviewHolder.rating = (RatingBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rating);//rating starts
                TabviewHolder.Submit = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);

                // Save the holder with the view
                convertView.setTag(TabviewHolder);
            } else {


                TabviewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }


            final Faculty mFac = facultylist.get(position);//*****************************NOTICE

            // TabviewHolder.rating.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(setOnRatingBarChangeListener(TabviewHolder, position));
            TabviewHolder.rating.setTag(position);
            TabviewHolder.FacultyName.setText(mFac.getEmployeename());
           // TabviewHolder.FacultyName.setTag(position);
            my_name = mFac.getEmployeename().toString();

            my_email = mFac.getEmployeeid().toString();
            feedbackresult = String.valueOf(rating);

           // ratingBar.setRating(rating);
            //my_rating = mFac.getRatingStar();
            TabviewHolder.rating.setRating(mFac.getRatingStar());

            // TabviewHolder.rating.setTag(position);
            // my_rating = hi.toString();

            // rating.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(getApplicationContext());
            //   TabviewHolder.ModuleName.setText(mFac.getSubject());


            TabviewHolder.rating.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
                public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating,
                                            boolean fromUser) {

                    feedbackresult = String.valueOf(rating);
                 hi = feedbackresult;
                    // if(!fromUser) return;
                   // Faculty item = getItem(position);
                   // item.setRatingStar(rating);
                    int index = (Integer) (ratingBar.getTag());

                    mFac.setRatingStar(Float.parseFloat(feedbackresult));
                    //amount=Float.parseFloat(feedbackresult);
                    // TabviewHolder.rating.setRating(Float.parseFloat(feedbackresult));
                    Log.d("feedback", "feedback is: " + feedbackresult);


                }
            });


            return convertView;
        }

        /*private RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener onRatingChangedListener(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
            return new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float v, boolean b) {
                    FacultyName item = getItem(position);
                    item.setRatingStar(v);
                    Log.i("Adapter", "star: " + v);
                }
            };
        }*/

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return facultylist.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Faculty getItem(int position) {
            return facultylist.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }
    }


    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView FacultyName;
        RatingBar rating;
        Button Submit;
    }

    private class FacultySyncerBg extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void> {
        ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // dialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);

            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Feedback.this, "Faculty Feedback!", "Fetching Faculty List", true);

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

            //CALLING WEBSERVICE
            Faculty(programtype);


            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {


            if (!facultylist.isEmpty()) {
                //  FacultyList.setVisibiltity(View.VISIBLE) ;


                courseEmptyLayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);

                if (FacultyList.getAdapter() != null) {
                    if (FacultyList.getAdapter().getCount() == 0) {
                        FacultyList.setAdapter(facultyListAdapter);
                    } else {
                        facultyListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                } else {
                    FacultyList.setAdapter(facultyListAdapter);
                }
            } else {
                courseEmptyLayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
                // FacultyList.setVisibiltity(View.GONE) ;

            }


            progressDialog.dismiss();

        }
    }


   /* @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if (isVisibleToUser && isResumed()) {

            new FacultySyncerBg().execute("");
        }
    }//end**/


    //**************************SECOND ASYNC TASK*********************************

    private class SendFeedbackSyncerBg extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        ProgressDialog progressDialog;


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Feedback.this, "Faculty Feedback!", "Uploading your ratings", true);
        }


        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            //Call Web Method from webService

            // FeedBackResponse=WebService.sendfeedback(programtype,employeemailid,employeename,feedbackresult);
            //  uploaddata = parid(faculty_name, email, rate, "getUserInfo");
            uploaddata = parid(rate, my_name, my_email, "getUserInfo");

            return null;
        }// doInBackground Process

        @Override
        //Once WebService returns response
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            if (uploaddata == false) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not Done!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {

                courseEmptyLayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Thanks for Feedback!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        }// End of onPostExecute

       /* @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getApplicationContext(), "Faculty Feedback!", "Uploading your ratings", true);
        }*/


    }
```

Comment: you need to use the WHERE clause e.g WHERE name="TheName" -- you need to add the database code in your question, i don't see any

Comment: I am storing in web service, calling web service from asynch task

Comment: this web service, is your own or 3rd party?